# Celerybeat execute task

Tags: python, celery

I have celery task:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def update_task():
    ....
```

I add this task to celerybeat in the settings:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "update-task-on-mathmod.org": {
        "task": "manager.update_task",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
    }
}
```

My projects structure:

[image]

Setting is in the `settings.py`, task define in `application.py`. How start periodic task?

I run `celery beat -A application`. Output:

```
celery beat v3.1.18 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,470: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,470: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,482: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<Entry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,483: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,495: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True, u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.2.4'}, mechanisms: [u'AMQPLAIN', u'PLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,497: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!
[2015-07-30 11:27:16,498: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes
```

Comment: Run celerybeat like you run your workers.

Comment: @user2097159 do you mean `celery -A application worker`?

Comment: Sort of It looks something like `celery beat -A application`

Comment: @user2097159 Is it so important?

Answer (score 2):

In order to process "scheduled" tasks you need to run "celery beat"
as @user2097159 said.

```
celery -A <project> beat -l debug
```

To run workers for normal tasks (task you execute asynchronous) you need to launch a worker

```
celery -A <project> worker -l debug
```

-l meas log-level equals to debug, good for development.
A good practice is to leave celery to set the tasks names instead of set name="something".
When the worker run it will show a message with the registered tasks, be sure you tasks have been registered by celery.
As soon as your tasks be sent to a worker or the beat you will see a log entry in its console.

Comment: Good you 've been able to found that.

Comment: It looks like you are using the "wrong" name  for your task.
The task's manager should be "manager.applications.update_task" not "manager.update_task".
You can confirm this by entering to the django shell import the task and check the name attribute.

`from manager.application import update_task` then do this 
 `print update_task.name`